# How do I create a map of addresses?

Tags: qgis, vector, address

This is a tricky one.

A little context first: Bentiu wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bentiu + OSM map of Bentiu refugee camp, South Sudan: http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=16/9.3314/29.7920

My task is to come up with a map of the dwellings and the facilities in the camp, each with their corresponding address.

For this I have (1) a schematic grid of the address system (.pdf), (2) indications on how the address system works (start numbering the buildings from the NW corner to E then S), and (3) the .shp of the individual houses and buildings extracted from aerial imagery analysis.

Problems: (a) while the grid assumes that buildings are perfectly-aligned squares, the shp shows different shapes of dwellings that partially follow the spatial organisation set up for the address system; (b) the drawing and the numbering are currently being used for healthcare provision and cannot be modified to fit the structure of the dwellings.

So far I have tried a couple of tricks unsuccessfully, mainly because the drawing is only a representation therefore cannot be georeferenced. I tried to assign every house in the .shp a number with $rownum but this did not work either because the order was not respected.

I'm more than willing to discuss any ideas!

Comment: Interesting challenge :)
How does the address system documented with the grid work ? Is that : 1, 2, 3, etc. starting from the NW corner and towards the S, then back to N at the end of the row etc. until SE corner ? Can you precise this ?

Comment: my bad! -- the address system starts at the NW corner with 1, then goes 2, 3, 4 towards the E until the end of row at 24, and then back at W in the next row and so on all the way to SE